# Angular2/Ionic 2 - Stripe error: "Cannot read property 'card' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments, ionic2, undefined-behavior

Im trying to integrate the stripe payment service into my ionic 2 application (similar to angular 2) and I've been running into issues. I followed this tutorial:

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/

It was written 4 months ago so it might be outdated, but I tried it anyways and when attempting the basic "StripeCheckout" method it gave me this error

"Cannot read property 'StripeCheckout' of undefined" -  from the console

payment.ts

```
openCheckout() {
  var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'API-KEY',
    locale: 'auto'
  });

  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    description: '2 widgets',
    amount: 2000
  });
}
```

I didn't add any imports relating to stripe in the .ts file, the only place I imported something related to stripe is in the index.html, which is unusual for angular2/ionic2 apps as its usually an import in the .ts

Index.html - I only added this line just above the closing body tag

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

I tested other methods including trying to add it using

-npm install stripe

-var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_...")

-The more complex/custom version of Strip forms

With not much success

Id like to know if there is a working solution for the stable releases of Angular2/Ionic2 of Stripe. If more code is required, I will provide it, but in essence, I followed the tutorial link.

EDIT: Changed "openCheckout(stripe:any)" to "openCheckout()", "stripe.StripeCheckout..." to "(window).StripeCheckout...", and hid the api key

Comment: I redacted the secret API key (`"sk_test_..."`) out of your message. You should never share secret keys. I recommend you roll out a new key by heading to your Stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys and clicking the "recycle" icon next to the key that needs replacing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I'm deleting my answer since you updated your question. I have to follow the tutorial and set this up to really dig into why it's not working.

Comment: Why don't you try this template Ionic2 with Stripe https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201702241736843/stripe-with-ionic2-quickly-and-easily-integrate-stripe-in-your-ionic2-app